# Definition of adjacent vertices in directed graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, definition

I was going through the text "Discrete Mathematics and its Applications" by Kenneth Rosen, where I found the definition of adjacent vertices in the context of directed graphs a bit different from the other books on graph theory and as well I could not quite find a clear cut reason behind the said definition.

> When $(u, v)$ is an edge of the graph $G$ with **directed edges**, $u$ is said to be ***adjacent to*** $v$ and $v$ is said to be ***adjacent from*** $u$. The vertex $u$ is called the initial vertex of $(u, v)$, and $v$ is called the terminal or end vertex of $(u, v)$. The initial vertex and terminal vertex of a loop are the same.

Now till date the books I have read, considers(for the edge $(u,v)$) $v$ as ***out adjacent to*** $u$ and $u$ as ***in adjacent to*** $v$, which is quite logical from the direction of the edges and the concept of in-degree and out-degree goes hand in hand with it.

Now in the definition of adjacent vertices by Rosen I find it sort of gives importance to the direction of the edge and gives not much importance to the very vertex which is supposed to be our subject.

$(u,v)$ means $u \sim\sim\sim> v$

So, there is from **"$u$ an edge *to* $v$"** $->$ **"$u$ is adjacent *to* $v$"**

Similarly, there exits to **"$v$ an edge *from* $u$"** $->$ **"$v$ is adjacent *from* $u$"**

Isn't this definition a bit weird>

Comment: Well, its perfectly fine: ''out adjacent to'' and ''in adjacent to''. Just one of several unique determinations of adjacency.

Comment: that is what I am saying, its fine, but i feel the out definition is weird

Comment: It's about as weird as someone saying "valence" instead of "degree," or "pendant vertex" instead of "vertex of degree 1." There are many different terms for the same things in graph theory, it's something you get used to over time. I wouldn't call this "weird," personally.

Comment: I don’t find it weird: I find Rosen’s terminology somewhat more natural than the alternative that you mention.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can you please give an example so that it would be possible for me to look at the definition in the same way as you do, which therefore would help me to satisfy myself that it is more natural than the alternative which I mentioned. Does it follow from the following statement: ```So, there is from "u an edge to v" −> "u is adjacent to v" . Similarly, there exits to "v an edge from u" −> "v is adjacent from u".```

Comment: @Abhishek: For me the *from* and *to* nicely capture the direction. Sn edge $u\to v$ is an edge **from** $u$ **to** $v$; from a point of view at $u$, the edge goes **to** $v$, so $u$ is adjacent **to** $v$, while from a point of view at $v$ it comes **from** $u$, so $v$ is adjacent **from** $u$. It’s not so much a matter of logic as of one’s individual feel for the language; when I first encountered the adjacent from/to terminology, I understood it immediately, without any explanation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you

Comment: @Abhishek: You’re welcome.